# can't find External Includes tab in visual studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/configuring-your-compiler-warning-and-error-levels/)
and in **increasing your warning levels** under For Visual Studio users says:
From C/C++ > External Includes tab, set External Header Warning Level to Level3 (/external:W3). This tells the compiler to compile standard library headers at warning level 3 (instead of 4) so that compiling those headers doesn’t trigger this warning.
and I don't find the External Includes tab searching in the ofical [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/external-external-headers-diagnostics?view=msvc-170) I don't understand how to use the commands eg: /external:W3 where to put it

Comment: It's not showing in that tutorial either, do you trust it?

Comment: Besides finding a better tutorial, look at top of VS menu, Project.  Bottom of drop-down, (appname) Properties.  Popup window left-side tree view, C/C++.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 Community has the menu exactly where the tutorial says: [https://pasteboard.co/DF4IW7RigNXY.png](https://pasteboard.co/DF4IW7RigNXY.png)

Comment: Have you tried to use Level4 and actually gotten any warnings from the standard library? If you do, please file a bug report instead of turning them off.

Comment: @BoP Yes I gotted something like warning because unsigned int to long

Comment: @drescherjm yeah I find that one but that doesn't work for the standar library anyway I found the one I was talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2022 Community Édition the option is as exactly where you described it. From your project properties you select ***C/C++*** to develop it and then you should find the ***External includes*** entry.
Once selected you'll see on the right panel few options that you can set among which you be able to change the warning level.